# Setting a variable with an alternative value if other options are blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a variable that must be set with a phone number, preferrably with a value from table A. If that's empty, it should be a value from table B (which is related to table A). If that's empty as well, it should be a value from another column on table B. Finally, if all of these are empty, it should be set to a string.

I tried to do this with `or`s:

```
telefone = a.telefone || a.associado_contato.first.telefone || a.associado_contato.first.celular || "não cadastrado"
```

But the result is `a.telefone` (the first option) even if it's blank.

I wanted to avoid nested `if`s. Is there a simple solution to this situation?

Comment: You can use `#presence`. It returns `nil` if the object is `blank?` and the object otherwise. Hence, you will be able to chain them with `||` like you are trying to do now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that even an empty String is truthy for ruby. So `"" || "1234"` is `""`.

With Rails, you can use `presence` :

```
"".presence || "1234"    # => "1234"
"567".presence || "1234" # => "567"
```

So your code could become :

```
telefone = a.telefone.presence || a.associado_contato.first.telefone.presence || a.associado_contato.first.celular.presence || "não cadastrado"
```

Assuming `a.associado_contato` is defined and has at least one element.